# Java Readers and Writers

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I have this little piece of code,where I chain an InputStreamReader and an OutputStreamWriter to File Streams, in order to better understand how Java handles different character sets (or better,different "character encodings").
here I create a file containing 256 bytes representing the numbers from 0 to 255 
and I try to read those bytes as if they were coded in, say, Cp855 (cyrillic),store them in Java native character encoding (which I understand is Unicode UTF-16) and then translate back those bytes as characters, this time in Cp1252 encoding (my Windows platform's default encoding):

```
import java.io.*;

class Test {  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
    if (args.length<2) {
      System.out.println("usage: java Test input_encoding output encoding");
      return;
    }
    InputStreamReader isr=null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw=null;
    try {
      File source=new File("source.txt");
      source.createNewFile();
      populate(source); 
      FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(source);  
      try {                
      isr=new InputStreamReader(fis,args[0]);
      }
      catch (UnsupportedEncodingException en) {
        System.out.println("input encoding not supported");
        isr=new InputStreamReader(fis);
      }
      FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("dest.txt");     
      try {     
        osw=new OutputStreamWriter(fos,args[1]);
      }
      catch (UnsupportedEncodingException en) {
        System.out.println("output encoding not supported");
        osw=new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
      }
      while (true) {
        int c=isr.read();
        if (c == -1) break;
        osw.write(c);
      } 
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      System.out.println("file error");
      return;
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      if (isr != null)
      try {
        isr.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("error closing resources");
      }
      if (osw != null)
      try {
        osw.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("error closing resources");
      }
    }
  }

  public static void populate(File file) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
    for (int i=0;i<256;++i)
      fos.write(i);
    fos.close();
  }

}
```

So what I expect is that,the two character encodings being different from 128 to 255 (I think that all codepages share the same first 128 ASCII characters,and then they go their own exotic way),Java maps the first 128 characters correctly from cyrillic to unicode and back to cp1252,while I should get a lot of substitute characters (question mark) in place of the characters that are in the cyrillic charset (and of course in Unicode) but not in Cp1252.
Instead I get this:

```
Ā̂Ԅ܆ईଊഌ༎ᄐጒᔔ᜖ᤘᬚᴜ἞℠⌢┤✦⤨⬪⴬⼮㄰㌲㔴㜶㤸㬺㴼㼾䅀䍂䕄䝆䥈䭊䵌低児卒啔坖奘孚嵜彞慠换敤杦楨歪浬潮煰獲畴睶祸筺絼罾㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿뮫㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿ꐿ㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㾭㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿ꜿꀿ
```

which look like chinese ideograms to me...????

**EDIT:** now I close the stream when I populate the file and call populate() before opening the input stream on it,resulting in a much cleaner code.
But the results are the same.

Comment: Post a simple, complete program reproducing the issue, and taking no argument: hard-code the encodings, and write the input file in the program: like that one: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/8755296579dad404e5d8. Also tell us how you open and view the destination file.

Comment: @JBNizet this is as simple as it gets,the output is at the end of my question, I use Windows notepad to view the file contents (my default encoding being Cp1252,I am surprised to see chinese gliphs..or everything else than western european characters..)

Comment: The problems are that the code above is incomplete: we don't know how you created the source file. We don't know why you create a new source file, what populate does, and what exact arguments you pass. What happens when you execute the code I posted in the gist? What happens when you open the result in a decent text editor, which tells you what encoding it used to interpret the file and allows changing it (like Notepad++ for example)

Comment: @JBNizet sorry,there was some code missing, check my edit

Comment: @JBNizet if I run your code it works as expected ...mmmh...

Comment: Your code also runs as expected, but on a Mac. It is not clean though: you open a FileInputStream on an empty file, then open a FileOutputStream on the same file to populate it. You don't close the OutputStream. Then you read from the file that is still opened in write mode by the populating OutputStream. Populate the file first, close the stream used to populate it, and then only start reading from the file. Just like... my code does.

Comment: @JBNizet I close the FileOutputStream fos I use to populate the file. But the result is the same..even if I populate the file and close the stream before opening the FileInputStream on the same file

Comment: @JBNizet if I open the dest.txt with notepad++ I get the expected result.
But I can't understand why notepad misinterprets my file, while it correctly reads the file produced by your code!
It seems like it gets misled as to what format the file is....